# Problem placing attribute in dimensional layout

Tags: database, database-design, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact-table

I am doing a small exercise, I need to create a small dimensional design that deals with the tsunamis that have occurred in different countries over the years. I have created a "Country" dimension and a "Location" dimension. In each record of the provided table comes (or may not come) the longitude and latitude in which the place is located. My question is where should I put such attributes, whether in the fact table or in the location dimension. My understanding is that in the fact table it should only contain metrics and the foreign keys of the dimensions. However, I don't know how correct it can be to add the longitude and latitude to the location dimension, since by having the values a very wide range, many records are being created in the "Location" dimensional table. Would it be more appropriate to put those attributes in the fact table?
[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should merge Location and Country into a single Location dimension (country is an attribute of location) and hold lat and long in the dimension

Answer (score 1):

On the fact table.  This is exactly like a fact that has a time attribute, with sub-second resolution.  It's not necessary to create a dimension table containing every possible point in time, or every possible lat/long.

Comment: Thanks. And what happens if I have some attributes that categorize an event, for example I have several fields that are categories to classify them, for example 'EarthquakeClass' or 'TsunamiClass', should I create a dimension for each one?

Comment: Typically yes.  If an EarthquakeClass has additional attributes, like min/max Richter scale, or depth, then absolutely.  But typically it's worth having dimension tables for every categorical attribute to provide a list of all possible values for users to select from without querying the fact table.